# Django i want create a function which can be run from any page from the website and do its process and return on the same page

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Django i want create a function which can be run from any page from the website and do its process and return on the same page

What i want to is to create a button to add to cart i have writted function but the time come from returning from the function i use redirect to cart page but i want that there are lots of types of product pages and i want they must redirect to the same page from where they come and use the same function to do that any idea

```
@login_required(login_url='login_signup')
def add_cart(request,id):
    prod = Product.objects.get(id = id)
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id = _cart_id(request))

    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
            cart_id = _cart_id(request)

        )
       
    cart.save()

    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product = prod,cart = cart)
        cart_item.quantity = cart_item.quantity + 1
        cart_item.save()
        # print("I was tries")
        customer = request.user
        cust = Customer.objects.get(user = customer)
        # print(f"The customer is {cust}")
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
        customer = request.user
        cust = Customer.objects.get(user = customer)
        # print("Cart except is also being hit")
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
            product = prod,
            quantity = 1,
            cart = cart,
            user = cust, 
            
            
        )
        cart_item.save()

    return redirect('/cart/cart_page')
```

Here is the  function i use to add to cart i want it to redirect to the same page from where it comes not always to  the cart page because i will trigger same function from many places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` to the previous url the user come from.

```
@login_required(login_url='login_signup')
def add_cart(request,id):
    # Lot of code
    #Redirect to previous url if exist else '/cart/cart_page'
    previous_url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/cart/cart_page')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(previous_url)
```

**Note :** i strongly recommend you to use *named ur* like `'cart_page'` defined in the `urls.py` file (`path('cart/cart_page',views.cart_page,name='cart_page')`) instead of *hard coded url* like `'/cart/cart_page'`

Comment: suppuse i am on the link 127.0.0.0:8000/products i hit add to cart so now the url become 127.0.0.0:8000/cart/add_to_cart now it will run the function after lots of code when time comes to return it ask for the previous url which is cart/add_to_cart for him dont you think it keeps add product until we stop i did something like this and i get what i am telling

Comment: i use name url until i am having any priamry key or any input in my url

Comment: If you were at `127.0.0.0:8000/products` and add a product to cart then you will be redirected to `127.0.0.0:8000/products` because `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') = 127.0.0.0:8000/products`

Comment: Try it and let us know